# Catching selection events in Bootstrap 4 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap 4 Dropdown elements to create two dropdown lists which both fetch their itmes from firebase-datastore. The selected item in the first one (car make) is supposed to set the content of the second (car model) dropdown.

But I'm having problems to catch any event containing information about which item in the dropdown that was selected. When trying to catch the `<a>` element I get no event. I've tried catching both `id="action-id"` as `$('#action-id').click(function(e)` and `class="dropdown-item"` as `$('.dropdown-item').click(function(e)` in the code below but without success.

```
$('.dd-select-make-menu').click(function(e) {
    var nameTarget1 = e.currentTarget;
    var nameTarget2 = e.relatedTarget;
    console.log(nameTarget1);
    console.log(nameTarget2);
    console.log(nameTarget1.innerHTML);
    console.log(nameTarget1.getAttribute("data-name"));
});
```

But if I tried to catch the parent `$('.dd-select-make-menu').click(function(e)` I did catch it and can trigger the function. But then I got the whole HTML structure within and I can't get out the information about which item was clicked.

The HTML looks like:

```
 <div class="dropdown dropDownMakeList" id="dd-select-make">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" type="button" id="brands-select-button";">All Brands;</button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dd-select-make-menu" role="menu" id="dd-select-make-menu">
            <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="action-id" data-name="SAAB">SAAB</a>
            <a role="presentation" href="#" class="dropdown-item" id="action-id" data-name="Volvo">Volvo</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've searched and tested many variants without luck. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or shold I've been using some other BS4 component?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right lines with your `$('.dd-select-make-menu').click(function(e)` - you just need to examine `e.target.innerHTML` and you should find it gives you the text of the item clicked on.